# Create in R a dataframe column that indicates how many times each row value has been sampled

Tags: r, random, counter

I am using R to draw a random sample of 24 elements (species) out of a vector containing 36 elements. As I have to repeat this process several times, I would like to create a data frame in which the first column is the name of the species and the second is a counter of the number of times in which the species has been sampled. So, at the end of the first sampling i would have something like:

```
   Plot_1                      Freq
   Agrostis castellana         1
   Amaranthus hybridus         1
   Ambrosia artemisiifolia     1
   Bromus secalinus            0
   ...                         ...
```

Then, after the second extraction I would have

```
   Plot_1                      Freq
   Agrostis castellana         2      #extracted both in Plot1 and Plot2
   Amaranthus hybridus         1      #extracted only in either Plot1 or Plot2
   Ambrosia artemisiifolia     1
   Bromus secalinus            0      #not extracted yet
   ...                         ...
```

I've looked in the internet but I can't seem to find a solution :( 
Please help! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a small example :

```
#convert your vector into factor
species <- factor(letters)
#Iteration 1
tab <- stack(table(sample(species, n)))

repeat_sample <- function(df, x, n) {
   tab <- stack(table(sample(x, n)))
   tab[1] <- tab[1] + df[1]
   return(tab)
}

#Iteration 2
tab <- repeat_sample(tab, species, 15)


#   values ind
#1       0   a
#2       1   b
#3       1   c
#4       0   d
#5       0   e
#6       1   f
#7       1   g
#8       2   h
#9       1   i
#10      0   j
#....

#Iteration 3
tab <- repeat_sample(tab, species, 15)
```

Replace `species` with the vector that you have and 15 with number of samples you want to draw i.e 24.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I needed! Thank you!!